# WebApi how to send asyncronous email after returning response to user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, smtp

Emails are taking too long to send (sometimes up to 7-8) seconds.

I want to send a response back to my clients without them having to wait for the email to send. Is this possible?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Action()
{
  //Do something
  await email.sendAsync(); //Can take up to 10 seconds...
  return Ok();
}
```

I can remove the await, but I obviously get a `An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would want to offload this work onto some other process, maybe a queue and then have some subscribers process off that queue to send the email but that is a lot of work and we live in the real world.

You can use

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => email.sendAsync());
```

to get something *quite* reliable up and running.

Comment: This is the correct advice. To expand, you generally don't want your web servers resources being taken up by doing work on background threads. Usually you want them to be able to be very scalable to handle as many requests as possible. One way you could achieve this is by throwing the email data in a service bus queue and then have a worker server somewhere else pop stuff off the queue and process it as it can. This way you can respond from your API instantly.